# Cannot redeclare class Google_Service_Drive

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am using google api client for uploading a file to drive, ran the quickstart example given in [google developer site](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) to list the files which is working fine.

In order to insert a file in specific parent folder I am using two objects (see the two lines below) which are causing an error shown below.

Lines that are causing error (second line is causing the error):

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Google_Service_Drive in C:\xampp\htdocs\driveapi\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Drive.php on line 729
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\driveapi\drive_client.php:0
PHP   2. spl_autoload_call() C:\xampp\htdocs\driveapi\drive_client.php:92
PHP   3. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp\htdocs\driveapi\drive_client.php:92
PHP   4. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\xampp\htdocs\driveapi\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:301
```

Full code: (only last two lines are added by me, rest is from google developer site)

```
<?php require __dir__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'drivephp');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __dir__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive")));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
    }
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$parentId = null;

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
//      'pageSize' => 10, 'fields' =>
//      "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
    }
}

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();

?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avil, I'm guessing you ran into the same issue that I ran into.  I followed the "quickstart" instructions on this page:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php#prerequisites

to install the appclient:1.* using composer and it then says to:

"Download and extract this zip file and copy Drive.php to vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/, replacing the existing file."

I got the same error and became suspicious so I checked on GIT and looked at the history of this file:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php

You'll notice that the "v1-master" version of Drive.php is almost 2,000 lines of code shorter than the prior release in October 2015.

All of the code for your "Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference" (I was looking for the Google_Service_Drive_Property class) is missing from the newest release.

I literally copied the code from the GIT repo's History (Oct 9 2015) into my Drive.php file and it's working fine now.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help. I downloaded older version of Drive.php, and had to change couple of functions like (getFiles -> getItems and setName -> setTitle etc), but it worked well in the end.